# Creating Maximum-Value Composite of MODIS images using QGIS

Tags: qgis, modis, hdf

I am trying to create a Maximum-Value composite of 4 MODIS images that are in .hdf format and I tried with 'Raster Composite' of ArcGIS but I think that's not the appropriate to do it. Can I do it using QGIS?

Data I Have: 05_2005, 06_2005, 07_2005, 08_2005 (MODIS Land Surface Temperature Data in HDF format)

I looked at this question 
[Creating Maximum-Value Composite using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86531/creating-maximum-value-composite-using-qgis)
but this is for raster in .TIF format.