# How do I use QGIS to merge maximum values of multiple TIF files into one "maximum value' raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have 14 rasters that represent water storage for the same area over a range of years, 2002 to 2015. I am looking for a way to find the maximum value at each pixel location.

I am not looking for the maximum value for each raster; I am looking for the  maximum value for each pixel of 14 rasters at each location.

Comment: Are you looking to create a "maximum value composite raster" like in this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86531/creating-maximum-value-composite-using-qgis

Comment: I found another method here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150312/combining-multiple-overlapping-rasters-retain-maximum-value