# Assign values to raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I'm stack with a simple issue.

I have a raster (DEM) and what I want to do is to assign `-9999` where the pixel value of the DEM is `500` and leave all the other values as the original ones.

I tried:

```
 (  ( "dem@1" = 500)  * (-9999)) OR  (  ( "dem@1" != 500)  * "dem@1" )
```

but I get a new raster with `nan` and `1`.

Some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @underdark's answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48752/qgis-raster-calculater-syntax?rq=1) I think you need to do:

```
 (( "dem@1" = 500)  * -9999) +  (( "dem@1" != 500) * "dem@1" ))
```