# Compare two raster extents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, raster, raster-calculator

I have two grids, grid A representing observed extents of flooding and grid B representing simulated extents from a hydraulic model. The rasters have the same extent and grid size.

I want to be able to compare each pixel and create a new raster with 4 unique values (A/B/C/D equivalent in the table below) to show the difference between the two rasters:

[image]

If this was a shapefile field calculator problem I'd use a CASE logic like the one below but I'm struggling to identify a QGIS raster-based equivalent.  Can anyone suggest anything I could try?

```
CASE
    WHEN "Modelled" > 0 AND "Observed" > 0 THEN D
    WHEN "Modelled" = 0 AND "Observed" > 0 THEN C
    WHEN "Modelled" > 0 AND "Observed" = 0 THEN B
    WHEN "Modelled" = 0 AND "Observed" = 0 THEN A
END
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried the **Raster Calculator**? You can add many different expression with a similar syntax to that one of the vector **Field Calculator**

Comment: As far as I can see the standard raster calculator doesn't support CASE/ELSE or IF/ELSE statements.  SAGA grid calculator will support IF/ELSE but won't allow chaining of statements together; for example A>0 AND B>0.

Comment: you are right, but maybe you can achieve want you are looking for, with some logic statement. Maybe this answer can help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48752/qgis-raster-calculater-syntax

Comment: I tried that but grid calc seems to fall over with the AND used in "eq(g1>0 AND g2>0" - I'll explore some more.

Comment: @EdRollason - I forgot that `AND` isn't used. Try something like: `ifelse(gt(a,0)+gt(b,0),400,ifelse(eq(a,0)+gt(b,0),300,ifelse(gt(a,0)+eq(b,0),200,ifelse(eq(a,0)+eq(b,0),100,0))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the QGIS raster calculator for this, using boolean masks. An example:

```
(("grid1@1">0) AND ("grid2@1">0)) * 1
+ (("grid1@1"=0) AND ("grid2@1">0)) * 2
+ (("grid1@1">0) AND ("grid2@1"=0)) * 3
+ (("grid1@1"=0) AND ("grid2@1"=0)) * 4
```

where you can change `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` to be whatever values you like.

The way that this works is that the first part of each term is a boolean mask. `("grid1@1">0) AND ("grid2@1">0))` is True when your first condition is met, and it can be multiplied by your categorical value `D` (I used `1`). The next three terms match your next three conditions.

#### Note

Steven Kay notes in the comments that the same expression can be performed without using `AND` by replacing it with a `*`. In this case, the first term looks like

```
(("grid1@1">0) * ("grid2@1">0)) * 1
```

Comment: good answer, certainly works in 2.16. I think some older versions don't support AND, but you can replace AND with *, as QGIS treats false as 0 and true as 1. OR is slightly trickier, but you can use + and check that the answer > 0.

Comment: Older versions didn't support the AND so I'd looked elsewhere as I couldn't get the more complex syntax to work.  Good to know they've added it.  I'll test this out on the data.  Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that replacing AND with * returns identical results, at least in QGIS 2.16.

Comment: My syntax must have been wrong I guess!

Comment: This took me a while to check but this definitely works in 2.16.